# google api refresh token not working

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

google analytics reporting api gives:
`{u'error_description': u'Unauthorized', u'error': u'unauthorized_client'}`
i am `not` using service account . my application requires users to confirm acess. this part is working good. i can also get the users access token and refresh_token. but when i use this refresh_token to ask another `access_token` i get the error above. 
what am i missing? is there anything that i have to enable from `developers console` to get it working?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to request a new access token we can not help you debug what we cant see.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. make sure to include correct client id and secret that we get from developers console when sending request .